# 8-bit shift register Master Reset button not working

Tags: pic, integrated-circuit, schematics, shift-register

I'm using the 74HC595. The datasheet [can be found here.](https://www.docdroid.net/ijIZ32z/74hc595.pdf)

Everything works, just the only problem is the Master Reset button is not working. Pressing it to LOW doesn't do anything. I measured the voltage while HIGH and LOW. Which is MRh = 4.69V, MRl = 0.04V.

Looking at the datasheet. With Vcc at 4.5V (I'm using 4.98V). The HIGH level input voltage is 3.15vMIN. The LOW level input voltage using 4.5Vcc is 1.35vMAX. [Here's the schematic I drew.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lSjX.jpg) [And the breadboard,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1XYm.jpg) although not really helpful. Is it the pull up/down resistor values?

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you draw the schematic using the sites own schematic editor tool? Makes it much easier to read. Also, write down what it is you are *expecting* it to do vs what it is *actually* doing

Comment: from, your desctiption of the measured voltages you are using suitable pull-up/down resistors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MR only clears the shift register. To affect the parallel outputs, this cleared state needs to be clocked into the latch by a positive-going transition on ST_CP. All this is shown in the function table.

Comment: unfortunately, I have do downvote this. OP may have been doing as you suggest, but after clocking it in, it isn't clearing. This is why I asked for more information in the comments. As OP stated everything works, except the reset, thus this answer would be more of a guess as it stands. Hopefully we will get some more information soon!

Comment: I have to upvote this as it seems to be the most reasonable guess.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat yeah, I agree it is a very reasonable guess, and likely correct, but it is still a guess. It is the question that needs clarifying first. As there is a lack of information in the question, a guess is better put in the comments than as an answer, hence my downvote. If the required information is put in and this is indeed correct, I will happily change my vote.

Comment: Although I will say these situations are frustrating when people ask a question then don't bother to return to look at answers or comments as this could well be the answer.

Comment: I think this answer is correct - however your low input levels are a bit high (because of the LEDs/resistors) and worse likely to be noisy - the diodes (LEDs) will turn off leaving the upper side (your inputs) essentially with an iffy sort of state - essentially high impedance

Comment: You're right...